# Pedaling and Braking of a Bicycle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

How exactly does a bicycle accelerate and decelerate when pedaling and braking?

Comment: I'm not sure that this question is on-topic for our community. If it had been submitted without the self-answer, it would certainly be closed as "too broad" or "needs focus." In most cases, a bad question isn't made on-topic by a good answer.

Comment: @rob Well. I'd ideally want to keep the answer running. Is there any way, planning on covering all elements of the bicycle in a couple days. is there any way to make this some sort of wiki regarding the bicycle?

Comment: The answer seems ok at first sight, but the question should address the forces at pedaling and braking, otherwise it is indeed to broad.

Comment: I don't think this is on topic at all. Engineering, too broad, unclear, homework, etc. Take your pick, it falls afoul of all of them.

Comment: @KyleKanos why is it too broad for engineering?

Comment: @Yukterez, would it be fine if I edit the question as I expand the answer?

Comment: As long as your answer is the only one I don't see a problem with editing, but if you get more answers you should't edit the question too much afterwards. Expanding is ok in general, but since most questions are supposed to be about one point adding too many subchapters could make it too long for that, it shouldn't get to the size of a whole PDF paper.

Comment: @rob. It would also be helpful if you were to tell how I could pull this off without the question being closed for off topic. Generally, bicycle related questions are asked here and it would be a much more useful resource here than at any other stack exchange sites.

Comment: @DevNotTaken There is a comma separating engineering and too broad, indicating two distinct elements of a list.

Comment: You may want to see if this question would be on-topic over at [bicycles.se] (which does have a [physics tag](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics))

Comment: It seems like you have written this nice introduction to the mechanics of a bicycle and are "shopping" for a place to put it. I'm not sure whether a comprehensive article on the bicycle is a good fit for any Stack Exchange Q&A community; it's just not our format. There are also also interesting physics questions which your post ignores. For example, the same braking (n.b. not "breaking") force is more effective at stopping a bicycle when applied to the front wheel versus the back wheel, because of angular momentum conservation. There is also …

Comment: … the famous question of why a rolling bicycle falls over more slowly than a stationary one, which turns out to be more interesting than just the gyroscopic effect. There is a classic Physics Today article on that question, which rejects the hypothesis "the bicycle is a very narrow steamroller, held up by the width of its tires," and ends with the author constructing both "uncrashable" and "unrideable" bicycles by varying the shape of the front fork.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanism of the Bicycle.

1. **Forward movement due to pedaling**

When you start pedaling, you exert a net force $F$ on the pedal. The pedal is connected to the sprocket by the crankshaft. This force $F$ introduces a torque $\tau_p$ in the sprocket which then pulls the chain inducing a tension in it which introduces a torque $\tau_b$ in the sprocket attached to the rear wheel.

[image: Chain System]

The sprocket attached to the rear wheel experiences less torque and more rotations as compared to the sprocket attached to the pedal. This is due to the difference in their sizes and the number of tooth in the sprocket.

$\tau_{p} = F\cdot \bar{R}$

Since the tension in the chain is constant,
$\frac{\tau_{p}}{R} = \frac{\tau_{b}}{r} \implies \tau_{b} = \frac{r}{R}\cdot\tau_{p} = \frac{r \bar{R}}{R}\cdot F$

Generally, the cycle wheel has a good traction with the ground and doesn't slip.

[image: Cycle 1]

Due to this traction, when the torque $\tau_w$ makes the wheel rotate, the static friction force $f_1 = \frac{\tau_w}{\bar r}$ acts on the rear wheel and pushes the bicycle forward.

While the cycle is accelerated forward, the front tire also starts rolling due to the torque of friction force $f_2$ acting on it. $f_2$ will act on the opposite direction of motion which would make the net force $F_{net} = f_1 - f_2$.

When this continues, this increases the velocity of the cycle because there is a net acceleration in the bicycle due to $F_{net}$.

2. **Continued forward movement due to Inertia**

When we stop pedaling, there is no force applied by you on the pedals which means $\tau_p=\tau_b=\tau_w=0$. This also means $f_1 = f_2 = 0$ and there is no static friction force acting on the bicycle.

There are a lot of resistive forces acting on the bicycle such as air resistance, rolling friction, internal resistive forces in the bearings and these forces add up and slow down the moving bicycle.

This is also why you can't ride a bicycle to a million meters per second. At one point, the dissipative forces would be equal to $F_{net}$ which would result in the bicycle achieving a terminal velocity.

This terminal velocity can be increased by putting more force on the pedals. I'd rather reach my destination a couple minutes late.

3. **Braking of the Bicycle**

There are 2 brakes in a bicycle, front and rear brakes which consist of a rubber clamp which tightly presses on the wheel to quickly stop their spin.

When the brake/s are applied, the rubber in the clamp presses tightly on the wheel, increasing the normal force and thus the friction force.

The friction force acts on the periphery of the rim of the wheel, thus maximizing its torque.

1. Front/Rear Brake is Applied

If rear brake was applied :
[image: Rear Brake]

If front brake was applied :
[image: Front Brake]

2. If both Brakes were Applied

[image: Both Brakes]

4. **Multiple Gears**

A lot of bicycles nowadays comes with a multi sprocket system that we can change while riding the bicycle.

There is a piece called the cassette which has multiple sprockets ordered from large to small.

When we are going at a high speed, it quickly becomes rather hard and tiring for us to keep pedaling at such speeds. At this moment, we can switch the gear to a different one which increases the tooth ratio and hence, reduce the speed of pedaling while maintaining a higher speed.

[image: Gears]

$\frac{\tau_{1b}}{r_1} = \frac{\tau_{2b}}{r_2} \implies \tau_{2b} = \frac{r_2}{r_1}\cdot\tau_{1b}$

This also reduces the torque for a particular applied force $F$ which reduces the acceleration. This is why, it is preferred to start cycling at lower gears and switch to higher ones at higher speeds.

I have spent a lot of time on this and I have some more topics such as turning of the bicycle to be covered. Will update it soon.

Also if you were to find any mistakes in the guide, please leave a comment asap and I will fix it immediately.

If you need any clarity on how a particular part of the bicycle works, leave a comment and I will add some more pictures and theory to cover that segment in detail.